# How do I make my PNGs have transparent thumbnail in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, png, thumbnails

Example provided below of the issue (where a black PNG is all black)

[image]

Comment: Try to clear the Thumbnails using Disk Cleanup, Windows will generate new thumbnails for files. Update the question if the problem persists after that.

Comment: Still the same, unfortunately. https://i.imgur.com/4kVNosq.png